# mongoose - update a updatedAt field while creating a new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code snippet.

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: ownerData.email })
            .select('-_id -__v -updatedAt')
            .lean();
        if (!user) {
            throw new HttpException(404, 'User not found');
        }
        await User.deleteOne({ email: ownerData.email });

        console.log(user);

        const newUser = await User.create({
            ...user,
            ...{
                address: ownerData.address,
                city: ownerData.city,
                state: ownerData.state,
            },
            _id: ownerId,
        });
        await newUser.save();
```

so basically what I want to do is delete the old user that is already present create a new one with the details of the old one. But unfortunately even though I am not taking the old `updatedAt` field, the old `updatedAt` field is getting populated on the new user object doc as well.

There is a chance that the ownerId can be the same as the old _id. I believe it's because of that, but I don't get around this problem.

Thanks

### EDIT

I got another interesting lead on this problem.

Since I am considering `createdAt` at the very first line of code

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: ownerData.email })
            .select('-_id -__v -updatedAt')
            .lean();
```

The new doc is taking the time from this `createdAt` field. Once I removed and checked the newUser is being created at a new time. Is there any relationship between `createdAt` and `updatedAt` ?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(user);` ?

Comment: It contains the created at field and all, but does not have updatedat field

Comment: What about `_id `?

Comment: What about it? I am ignoring that as well

Comment: Do you have updatedAt if you don't pass _id  to the newUser?

Comment: Do you have `{timestamps: true}` in schema  definition? It will automatically add createdAt and updatedAt field while creating.

Comment: Yes I do have timestamps true, but the timestamps that's being added are old docs one, not the newly created timestamp

Comment: @AlexBlex i didn't understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
But I don't have a clear explanation to why. If anyone have a perfect explanation please comment below.

I solved the problem with updating the `updatedAt` field separately after the schema creation.

```
const newUser = await User.create({
        ...user,
        ...{
            address: ownerData.address,
            city: ownerData.city,
            state: ownerData.state,
        },
        _id: ownerId,
    });
    newUser.updatedAt = new Date();
    await newUser.save();
```

I don't know why this is not getting updated when I do like below

```
const newUser = await User.create({
        ...user,
        ...{
            address: ownerData.address,
            city: ownerData.city,
            state: ownerData.state,
        },
        _id: ownerId,
        updatedAt: new Date()
    });     
    await newUser.save();
```

Comment: I think `updatedAt = new Date()` inside an object will generate a syntax error. I might be `updatedAt: new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `timestamps` option to `false` in your call to `save()` should fix your problem.

```
await newUser.save({timestamps: false});
```

Here's [an issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8071) on the mongoose project where the reasoning is explained.